# Return last values from specific position in array

Tags: php, arrays

There's an array of pages,

```
$pages = array(
   1,
   2,
   3,
   ...

   100,
   101
);
```

And there's a variable `$current_page`. All I'm trying to do is pagination in digg-like style, so that it would look like this,

```
< 4 5 6 7 .... 15 16 17 18 >
```

The first thing that comes to mind is to get last and previous array values from specific position that equals to `$current_page`.

So I started with a basic `for` loop, but the problem is that amount of pages could be very large, so I don't think that's an efficient thing to do. Is there any another proper way of doing this? (maybe via native `array_*` functions)?

Comment: What exactly does the output look like for a given `$current_page`? And do you like stackoverflow type pager?

Comment: @SalmanA Yeah indeed I need exact pagination like on `stackoverflow.com/users`

Comment: I have ASP code for this. I'll see if it could be converted to PHP.

Comment: @SalmanA I think I can read `C#/VB` as well, so I'd appreciate if you share this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following function builds StackOverflow like pagination. The objectives are:

- First and last links must be visible always
- Previous and next links must be visible always
- At most 4 links before/after the current page should be visible

While the following function displays the complete pager, we are primarily interested in how to calculate the surrounding pages **a** and **b** as a function of **current page**, **pager size** and **page count**.

```
function so_like_pager($current_page, $page_count, $pager_size = 4) {
    if ($current_page <= $pager_size) {
        // the pager for first 4 pages starts from 1
        $a = 1;
        $b = min(1 + $pager_size, $page_count);
    } else {
        // the pager for remaining pages ends at current page + 2
        // and starts so that 4 links are shown
        $b = min($current_page + ($pager_size >> 1), $page_count);
        $a = $b - $pager_size;
    }
    // return array("show_from" => $a, "show_upto" => $b);
    echo '<p>';
    if ($current_page !== 1) {
        echo '<a href="' . so_like_pager_page(1) . '">' . 1 . '</a> ';
    } else {
        echo '<b>' . 1 . '</b> ';
    }
    if ($a > 1 + 1) {
        echo '<span>...</span> ';
    }
    for ($i = $a; $i <= $b; $i++) {
        if ($i !== 1 && $i !== $page_count) {
            if ($current_page !== $i) {
                echo '<a href="' . so_like_pager_page($i) . '">' . $i . '</a> ';
            } else {
                echo '<b>' . $i . '</b> ';
            }
        }
    }
    if ($b < $page_count - 1) {
        echo '<span>...</span> ';
    }
    if ($current_page !== $page_count) {
        echo '<a href="' . so_like_pager_page($page_count) . '">' . $page_count . '</a> ';
    } else {
        echo '<b>' . $page_count . '</b> ';
    }
    echo '</p>';
}
function so_like_pager_page($page) {
    return 'page-' . $page . '/';
}
```

Tests:

```
so_like_pager(1, 100);
so_like_pager(2, 100);
so_like_pager(3, 100);
so_like_pager(4, 100);
so_like_pager(5, 100);
so_like_pager(6, 100);
so_like_pager(50, 100);
so_like_pager(99, 100);
so_like_pager(100, 100);
```

Output:

[image: Pagination code output]

PS: Note: I ported this function from ASP classic to PHP in a hurry and did not test against edge cases.

Comment: Yeah better than I have now. It would be nice if you could explain a purposes of `$b` and `$a` variables (*as it's a bit harder to read the code*)

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_surrounding_pages(array $pages, $current, $amount = 2) {
  $pages_idx = array_flip($pages);
  if (!isset($pages_idx[$current])) {
    return false;
  }
  $offset = max(0, $pages_idx[$current] - $amount);
  $limit = $amount + 1 + ($pages_idx[$current] - $offset);
  return array_slice($pages, $offset, $limit);
}    

$pages = range(1, 1000);
$current = 42;
get_surrounding_pages($pages, $current, 4); 
// array(38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46)

// this will work even if your number of pages is not continuous (eg: 1, 2, 6).
$pages = array(1, 2, 5, 6, 42, 234, 1048);
$current = 6;
get_surrounding_pages($pages, $current, 2); 
// array(2, 5, 6, 42, 234)

// also works if you reach the boundaries
$pages = range(1, 10);
$current = 2;
get_surrounding_pages($pages, $current, 2); 
// array(1, 2, 3, 4)
$current = 9;
get_surrounding_pages($pages, $current, 2); 
// array(7, 8, 9, 10)

// returns false if you ask a page that doesn't exists
$pages = range(1, 10);
$current = 42;
get_surrounding_pages($pages, $current, 2); 
// false
```

Comment: Yeah this is close to what I need (I need exact pagination like on stackoverflow.com/users), but seems like it does not work as expected, when I test it like `get_surrounding_pages(range(1, 200), 5, 10)`

Comment: If you don't say what result you get nor what result you expect I don't see how anyone can help you.

Comment: Well, If you run `get_surrounding_pages(range(1, 200), 5, 10)` this will return first pages starting from 1 up to 21. Again just take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/users style pagination and you'll see the point

Comment: Nope. now it returns up to 15 instead of 21. Almost the same thing. Again I want this: `get_surrounding_pages(range(1, 200), 5, 10)` to return an array like this : `Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 195, 196, 197, 200)`

Answer (score -1):

You can use PHP's `end` function to get the last entry of an array.

```
<?php

$a = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10 );
echo end($a);
```

You can also use `array_slice`, or `array_splice` to cut an array, or `array_pop`, which removes the last element and returns what was removed.

Comment: He wants the pages surrounding the current one, I don't see how getting the final entry in the array solves that.

Comment: But the question clearly asked for the "last values" from an array. I do think going to the end of array and then call prev() a few times is more efficient than looping from the current position if the array is long.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try [end](https://www.php.net/end). Should be more efficient than looping.