# array conditions

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array

```
$example=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16);
$limit=4 // 4 at the beginning only... 
//it used to get incremented automatically to 8,12,16....
```

At first i want `1,2,3,4`as an output for which i have done

```
foreach($example as $eg)
{
   if($eg>$limit)
     continue;
}
```

and i am easily getting `1,2,3,4` at the first then `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8` then`1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12`

But now i what i want is `1,2,3,4` at the very beginning then `5,6,7,8` then `9,10,11,12` lyk this... how can i get that???
please do help me... :)

AS the

```
foreach($example as $eg)
    {
       if($eg>$limit)
         continue;
    }
```

is returning only `1,2,3,4` at `$limit=4` and `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8` at `$limit=8`
i need `1,2,3,4` at `$limit=4` and `5,6,7,8` at `$limit=8`

Comment: Do you need that for pagination?

Comment: yea some kind of pagination....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23033253/1208233 I had the same question

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using the helpful built-in functions?

```
array_chunk($example,$limit);
```

Alternatively, for more page-like behaviour:

```
$pagenum = 2; // change based on page
$offset = $pagenum * $limit;
array_slice($example,$offset,$limit);
```

Comment: No, this is not how a Digg-Style pagination works under the hood. Therefore +0

Comment: @djay Edited to include a pagination option.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol thanx bt its returning an array actually i need to display only 1,2,3,4 at the beginning... then at another loading 5,6,7,8

Answer (score 1):

You would first chunk the array so each chunk has 4 elements, then loop through each chunk:

To change the numbers shown depending on which group, you could do:

```
 $group = $_GET['group'];
 $items = array_chunk($example, ceil(count($example)/4)[$group-1];
 echo implode(", ", $items);
```

Then you can go to

```
 yoursite.com/page.php?group=1
```

And it will output

```
1, 2, 3, 4
```

And when you go to

```
yoursite.com/page.php?group=2
```

It will output

```
5, 6, 7, 8
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

**You can try something like this**

```
$example=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16);
$limit = 8;
$limit -= 4;
for($i = $limit; $i < ($limit + 4); $i++)
{
    echo $example[$i].' ';
}
```

**Output**

```
//for $limit 4 output 1 2 3 4
//for $limit 8 output 5 6 7 8
//for $limit 16 output 13 14 15 16
```